# NHibernate mapping problem

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MOVIES_HISTORY](
 [DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [COUNT] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MOVIES_HISTORY_COUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MOVIES_HISTORY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [DATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Kinoplex.Models
{
    public class MoviesHistory
    {
        private DateTime date;
        private int count;

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get
            {
                return date;
            }
            set
            {
                date = value;
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return count;
            }
            set
            {
                count = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="Kinoplex.Models"
                   assembly="Kinoplex">

  <class name="MoviesHistory"
         dynamic-insert="true"
         dynamic-update="true"
         lazy="false"
         table="MOVIES_HISTORY">


    <id name ="Date" column="DATE" type="datetime">
    </id>

    <property name ="Count" >
      <column name="COUNT" sql-type="int" not-null="true"></column>
    </property>



  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Every other class is working, I only have problem with this one.

Executing query like:

```
IQuery query = this.session.CreateQuery("from MoviesHistory");
```

results in an exception:

MoviesHistory is not mapped [from MoviesHistory]

Anyone can tell me what is wrong? I suspect that id column might be wrong, but can't find anything about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `.hbm.xml` has it's build action set to **Embedded Resource** in your project, otherwise it won't be included in the mappings as nHibernate starts up.

Also, not positive it matters, but `DateTime` should have proper casing to be safe (not sure if the nHibernate parser cares anymore, it didn't at one point):

```
<id name="Date" column="DATE" type="DateTime">
```

Comment: I thought it was the SQL type so I wrote datetime instead of DateTime, but that doesn't seem to matter. The problem was in the build action. Thank you very much.